# DTCoreText Error Message after implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-text, dtcoretext

i tried to implement [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText). I follow this [guide](https://docs.cocoanetics.com/DTCoreText/docs/Setup%20Guide.html) and implemented it as git submodul, but now i get an error when i try to run my app. At the Moment i´m not doing any coding with DTCoreText. I just want to test my app if it works with the new imported Data...but it do not!

I got one warning:

```
Static Library was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'libDTCoreText.a' because its architectures 'armv7s' didn't contain all required architectures 'armv7'
```

which is in my opinion the reason for the following error which occour after the warning:

```
Apple Mach-O Linker Error:  no such file or directory: '/Users/-------------/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libDTCoreText.a'
```

I did not forget to implement the libDTCoreText.a in "***Link Binary With Libraries***", but it is always red? Is this maybe the Problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I had to check "Build Active Architecture Only" on each of the Project configurations (Debug, Release and Deployment) and in the Build Settings of the DTCoreText project targets.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/00oktoqgse83sph/Screenshot%202014-08-07%2014.08.47.png

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gcy6ynrzqs8i7c1/Screenshot%202014-08-07%2014.10.39.png